# Kubernetes authentication and authorization like Openshift

Tags: security, kubernetes, ldap, openshift, openid-connect

I am working on both Kubernetes and OpenShift. What I am missing in Kubernetes is the Authentication and Authorization mechanism that has OpenShift.

I want to manage users, limit users access to namespaces, advanced RBAC operations, etc..

I saw some integration of OIDC using Google or Github, but it is very limited and not really OpenShift-like..

Answer (score 0):

> I saw some integration of OIDC using Google or Github, but it is very
>   limited and not really OpenShift-like..

My understanding about "OpenShift-like.." is meaning various `identity providers` can be configure simply as specifying parameters in the configuration file, and provided various built in `authorization role` set as `default`.

Personally, I think `Kubernetes` might be configured like `OpenShift`, but it seems to struggle to implement your needs simply. You should configure manually to `apiserver` of `Kubernetes` and defined the `roles` you want or required based on `RBAC`.
Yes, `Kubernetes` have the features as follows, but it's not to configure as easy as `OpenShift`.

- Kunernetes

  - [Authenticating](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/)
  - [Using RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/)
- OpenShift

  - [Configuring authentication and user agent](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/install_config/configuring_authentication.html)
  - [Managing Role-based Access Control (RBAC)](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/manage_rbac.html)

`OpenShift` is `Enterprise Kubernetes` + `CI/CD` + `Support Services`, so `OpenShift` is extended from  basic `Kubernetes`. Additionally, it has implemented various comfortable features about authentication and authorization by simple format, because it's not only container orchestration but it is also enterprise solution.

Comment: Worth noting is that OpenShift Container Platform (OCP) is the Red Hat product you need a subscription for. OKD, is the upstream open source version that OCP is built from that anyone can use. So if you want OpenShift functionality for Kubernetes, but don't want to have to pay for a subscription for OCP, then use OKD (https://www.okd.io/) instead.